# Specifying data to plot in Seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I really like using Seaborn's `PairPlot` chart/function, but I wondered if there was a way to be a bit more specific about what plots to see.

For example, I have a `df` of stock prices. Let's say `Stock A`, `Stock B`, `Stock C`, `Stock D` etc.

Using `sns.pairplot(df)` I get the following:

[image]

What I would like to do is be able to plot for example, `Stock A`, `Stock B`, `Stock C`, against `Stock X`, `Stock Y`, `Stock Z`. SO A, B and C will appear along the X-axis, and X, Y and Z will appear along the Y-axis. This will of course result in to bar charts.

And as an extra point if anyone knows how I can display the line of best fit along with the r-squared number on each plot that would be amazing.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `x_vars`and `y_vars` indicating which columns you want see. [pairplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)

```
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C"], y_vars=["Stock X", "Stock Y", "Stock Z"])
```

Comment: Ah perfect, lovely answer thanks mate. I did actually see that in the documentation but wasn't really sure what it meant as I couldn't see any examples. Thanks again mate.

Comment: There is an example using that argument at some point, but I agree it's not the best worked one.

Answer (score 2):

you can use seaborn's [`PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) to do [regression plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html).  something like this should work:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(
    df,
    x_vars=["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C"],
    y_vars=["Stock X", "Stock Y", "Stock Z"]
)
g.map(sns.regplot)
```

Answer (score 1):

for bar graph:

```
sns.barplot(x=["Stock A", "Stock B", "Stock C"], y=["Stock X", "Stock Y", "Stock Z"], data=your_data)
```

for the latter you might wanna look at: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html